# Titanium Appcelerator Android - Open default soft keyboard in number view

Tags: android, keyboard, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

I have an address search field in my app. When this field gets focus I want to open the keyboard as in the following image.

[image: iOS Number Punctuation Keyboard]

It works fine for iOS when the keyboard type is set to Titanium.UI.KEYBOARD_NUMBERS_PUNCTUATION as in the following code

```
var search = Titanium.UI.createSearchBar({
        barColor:'#c8c8c8',
        autocorrect:true,
        hintText:'enter address',
        height:'43dp',
        top:'75dp',
        autocapitalization: Titanium.UI.TEXT_AUTOCAPITALIZATION_WORDS,
        keyboardType:Titanium.UI.KEYBOARD_NUMBERS_PUNCTUATION
    });
```

However on Android it appears as in the following image.

[image]

I am using Titanium mobile SDK 1.7.5

Answer (score 2):

You should probably add :

```
softKeyboardOnFocus : Titanium.UI.Android.SOFT_KEYBOARD_SHOW_ON_FOCUS
```

Unfortunately, [it may be overridden by the system](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.UI.Android.SOFT_KEYBOARD_SHOW_ON_FOCUS-property.html). Try it on another Android system (3.0 for example) if the problem persist.